# how to use datetimepicker with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

why I get this TS error:

```
Type '(newDate: Date) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: Event, date?: Date | undefined) => void) | (((event: Event, date?: Date | undefined) => void) & ((event: AndroidEvent, date?: Date | undefined) => void)) | (((event: Event, date?: Date | undefined) => void) & ((event: WindowsDatePickerChangeEvent, date?: Date | undefined) => void)) | undefined'.
  Type '(newDate: Date) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: Event, date?: Date | undefined) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'newDate' and 'event' are incompatible.
      Type 'SyntheticEvent<Readonly<{ timestamp: number; }>, Event>' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 37 more.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(36, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<Readonly<Readonly<ViewProps & BaseOptions & { maximumDate?: Date | undefined; minimumDate?: Date | undefined; }> & { ...; }> | Readonly<...> | Readonly<...>>'
```

Code:

```
 <DateTimePicker
   value={values.birthday}
   mode='date'
   display='default'
   onChange={(newDate: Date) => {
   setFieldValue('birthday', newDate);
  }}
 />
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

> Type '(newDate: Date) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: Event, date?: Date | undefined) => void)

You typed the (first) argument to `onChange` as a `Date`. This is not the function signature expected by the component you are implementing. Also, you shouldn't need to type the function arguments as it (the function) is being defined inline and TS can infer the type from the component definition.

You don't specify which package you are using. But I would try something like:

```
 <DateTimePicker
   value={values.birthday}
   mode='date'
   display='default'
   onChange={(_, newDate) => {
       setFieldValue('birthday', newDate);
   }}
 />
```

Edit: You may want to initialize `values.birthday` as a `Date` so the value you are setting matches the one provided by `onChange`. Also, note, `newDate` can be `undefined` per the `onChange` signature. Either define `values.birthday` as possibly `undefined` or call `setState` only if it is not `undefined`.

See [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/b_pAsrTOM). Also in comments.

Comment: now I get this: event and newDate are any

Comment: Here is a working snack. https://snack.expo.dev/b_pAsrTOM

Comment: my ts error still exists, event and newDate are any

Comment: Notice how my snack has no such errors. Please supply a minimal reproducible example